# Dynamically appending HTML elements using jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to build a button menu dynamically using Javascript, but I cannot make it work. 
I´m using Bootstrap as base style class.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="well">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Button 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Button 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Button 3</button>
    <small class="pull-right">Right Text</small>
</div>


<div id="myMenu">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var upperWell = $("<div class='well clearfix'>");

        $('myMenu').append(upperWell);

        var createButton = $("<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>Button1</button>");

        var updateButton = $("<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>Button 2</button>");

        var exportButton = $("<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>Button 3</button>");

        $(upperWell).append(createButton);
        $(upperWell).append(updateButton);
        $(upperWell).append(exportButton);

    });

</script>
```

The HTML code is what I need to build using Javascript.

The given Javascript code is not working.

Here is a fiddle that shows the code:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cox123456a/P7pTL/1/)

Help very much appreaciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten the `#` from the selector.

Should be this. 
`$('#myMenu').append(upperWell);`

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/P7pTL/2/

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please see here http://jsfiddle.net/hz37q/

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        var upperWell = $("<div class='well clearfix'>");

        $('#myMenu').append(upperWell); // <-- you miss hash 

        var createButton = $("<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>Button1</button>");

        var updateButton = $("<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>Button 2</button>");

        var exportButton = $("<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>Button 3</button>");

        $(upperWell).append(createButton);
        $(upperWell).append(updateButton);
        $(upperWell).append(exportButton);

    });
```